# Direct conversion between two bases

Tags: numbers, mit-scratch

I am looking to convert between two bases in Scratch. I would like a direct conversion, not one that goes to decimal as an intermediate step. Is there an algorithm or function that can do this for any two bases? If possible, could it have compatibility with bases beyond 10, preferably to 36?

I tried some algorithms that I learned in a number theory class but it's hard to transfer them over to code, especially with the limitations of Scratch.

Comment: I might want to add that my goal is to convert a save code made of 0s, 1s, and 2s, into base-36 so that I will get a much shorter save code, then reversing it and converting it back to base-3 for importing.

Comment: I would recommend to use base-27, for 3 reasons. (1) It's _much_ simpler to convert to base-3 and back; every base-27 digit directly maps to 3 base-3 digits. (2) Gives you sufficient slack to avoid vowels, thereby preventing inappropriate language that may otherwise show up in save codes; use BCDFGHJKLMPQRSTVWXZ23456789 as base-27 digits. (3) It only makes your save codes 8.7% longer compared to base-36; big deal.

Comment: Oh, great idea. I don't want certain words formed in my codes! How would you suggest programming base-3 to base-27 conversion then?

Comment: Simplest approach: two lists, `base-27` (holding 27 unique digits, as proposed earlier) and `base-3` (holding 27 unique combinations of 3 digits, all the way from 000 to 222). To convert (groups of) digits, [search](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Item_Number_of_()_in_()_(block)) in one list, [retrieve](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Item_()_of_()_(block)) from the other list.

Comment: Great! I will implement that now.

Comment: How long is your save code? Building on @RuudHelderman's suggestion, you can go to base-81 and pack four of your base-3 numbers into one.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Most Scratch operators are case-insensitive, so you'll have to leave the ASCII comfort zone for base-81. But then, given the vastness of Unicode, you could push it even further and pack 10 base-3 digits in a single character. That would then be known as base-59049. Argh...

Comment: @VladFeinstein, It's not that long. Base-27 was enough.